# Setting an option to NULL

Tags: r

Is it possible to set an `options` to `NULL` while using `getOption` with a default value other than NULL?

```
options("TEST" = NULL)
getOption("TEST")
# NULL

getOption("TEST", default=1)
# [1] 1
```

I would have expected the last line to return `NULL`.  Is this intended behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround: nest the (potentially `NULL`) value in a `list` and use that:

```
options(TEST = list(NULL))
getOption("TEST")[[1]]
# [1] NULL

getOption("TEST", default = list(1))[[1]]
# [1] NULL
```

Comment: You can see my comment on a deleted post, correct?  Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @richard Yes, I do. I appreciate the fact that you replied at all, by the way. :-)

Comment: Oh, absolutely.  I appreciate you commenting and giving me a chance to do something first, rather than just logging a downvote. I'm here to learn and (hopefully) help others at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Konrad for the answer.  This might be the best workaround, but I do hate littering my code with a slew of `[[1]]` -- although I'm not sure if there is any other way

Comment: @Ricardo Well you’d wrap it into a function, of course. Something like `getNullableOption`

Comment: @Konrad, In fact, exactly what I did.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

`options` is a named list, so setting an option to `NULL` is akin to removing that option.

It appears there is no way to have an option set to `NULL` while also allowing the use of `getOption` with an alternate default value.